# How to extract specific line from text file

Tags: powershell, text-files, line-numbers

I got a large log file (user.log) , eg:

```
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.407095
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.410345
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.410765
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.411187
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.411791
   2019-10-02 00:03:55.412657
```

How do I just extract the line number #3 from the log file as;

2019-10-02 00:03:55.410765

By using powershell script?

Comment: the `Get-Content` cmdlet has a `-ReadCount` parameter. if you set that to `3`, and pipe to `ForEach-Object {$Test = $_; break}`, you will have the 1st 3 lines of the file in `$Test`. you can get the 3rd one via `$Test[2]` ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **simple and *memory-efficient* approach suitable for processing *large* input files** is to combine `Get-Content` with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-Content user.log | Select-Object -Skip 2 -First 1
```

- `-Skip 2` instructs `Select-Object` to skip the first 2 input lines output by `Get-Content`.
- Therefore, it is the *3rd* line that is the first processed - and output - by `Select-Object`, and 
  `-First 1` makes it *stop* processing right afterwards, so that the rest of the file needn't be read.

---

A ***faster* approach**, **IF the portion of the file up to the desired line number is *small enough* to *fit into memory as a whole***:

```
(Get-Content -TotalCount 3 -ReadCount -3 user.log)[-1]
```

- `-TotalCount 3` tells `Get-Content` to read 3 lines (at most) in total.

  - `-ReadCount 3` additionally tells `Get-Content` to read all 3 lines *at once* into an array and send it through the pipeline *as a single object* - rather than *line by line* - this isn't *necessary*, but *speeds up* the command.
- `[-1]` then extracts the *last* element from the resulting array, which is the 3rd line.

---

**If the input file *as a whole* is small, the following solution is *simplest*:**

```
(Get-Content user.log)[2]  # add -ReadCount 0 to speed things up
```

That is, `Get-Content` reads *all* lines, which `(...)` collects in an array in memory, and `[2]` accesses the array's *3rd element*, i.e., the 3rd line.

A simple way of speeding up this solution would be to add `-ReadCount 0`, which makes `Get-Content` emit the array of all input lines itself, as a *single output object*, as opposed to emitting lines *one by one* and letting `(...)` collect them in an array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this and change the $target variable to whatever line you want to extract:

```
$content = Get-Content "path to user.log"
$count = 0
$target = 3

foreach ($line in $content) {
    $count += 1
    if ($count -eq $target) {
        $line
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's not a good approach for reading _large_ files, because it requires reading the _entire file_ into an array of lines, up front; if you are willing to pay that price, a much simpler solution would be: `(Get-Content "path to user.log")[2]`.